# Is it pure coincidence that the words for "reunification" and "German" are so similar (통일 and 독일)?

Tags: etymology

I once saw a documentary about Korean reunification with voice-over translation, and I wondered why they kept metioning Germany (until I realized what it was that they actually said:통일)

Comment: yes it is a coincidence

Comment: then what might be the etymological history of the first one?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%ED%86%B5%EC%9D%BC#Etymology

Comment: Yes. Just a coincidence. In Japanese, ドイツ (Its pronunciation is [doittsu], which sounds like Deutsche.) means Germany. Its transliteration is 獨逸. And the word was imported into Korea without any modification. According to the rule of reading Sino-Korean, the word is pronounced as 독일.

Answer (score 3):

The Chinese character of `통일` is `统一` (the same in Japanese).

The Chinese character of `독일` is `獨逸`, which was likely from Japanese word. This set of Chinese characters were chosen simply for its phonetic similarity. For more information, refer to [this wikitionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8B%AC%E9%80%B8).

So it is simply a coincidence.